# Learning the JAVA,but i'm in trouble

Tags: java, jersey

I start learning the JAVA,and I thought that it's more simple than C and more difficult than C#,so I have builded a project which using the JERSEY framework,and there some errors,would you like to help me fixed that errors?
here is my code 
https://github.com/abcdef123ghi/jerseytest

I have 5 errors,I dont know what's diffrenet with JAVA & C#,I'm just triing to write a JAVA project,the error is

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method checkAuth(String, String) is undefined for the type myresource   myresource.java /slwebservice/src/service   line 40 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method inserttherecord(String, List<invdatas>) is undefined for the type myresource myresource.java /slwebservice/src/service   line 43 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null myresource.java /slwebservice/src/service   line 31 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
This method must return a result of type int    invdataManager.java /slwebservice/src/domain    line 88 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date  invdataManager.java /slwebservice/src/domain    line 223    Java Problem
```

thanks
regards
Ken

Comment: Seeing the errors without the lines that triggered them is useless... That said, the errors you posted look pretty straight forward, for example, the method `checkAuth ()` accepts strings as arguments and you're sending it an object of type `myresource`

Comment: Start with simple things for learning. You could try [The Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Fine,but although I have bought a book which is Ivor Horton's beginning JAVA 7 edition. I have finished reading this book,but when errors  comes,I have no idea how to resolve these problems

Comment: @KenYup A book may give you the basics of the language, but debugging and problem resolution is something you can't learn from any book. The error messages are quite clear in this case, so you shouldn't give up yet. If you know Java basics, then `Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date` should be understood by you.

Comment: I am starting to really enjoy calling Java "the JAVA".  There is a nice ring to it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few compile errors in your code. I think you better follow some java tutorials and check the code again. Anyway I'll point out the errors and the solutions.

1. The method checkAuth(String, String) is undefined : There is no checkAuth method in your myresource.java. Please add it.
2. The method inserttherecord(String, List) is undefined : Same as above
3. The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null : int is a primitive value. So the default value for int is 0.  If you used Integer instead of int, then your operation is correct. So you need to change the code as this.`ivm.getRecordcount()==0`
4. This method must return a result of type int : The method `public int  inserttherecord(List<invdatas> invdatalist,String clino)` should return a int value. Your code does that but inside conditions and blocks. The idea is you should return a int value not you may return it. Al least put `return 0;` to the end of the method.
5. Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date : Here your method `private Date parseDate(String date)` should return `java.sql.Date` object But you return `return format.parse(date);`. This will return a `java.util.Date`. I think the return type of the method should be `java.util.Date`. It seems you import wrong class. Just import `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`.

Hope this will help you. Thanks